# omxplayer + livestreamer: twitch.tv streams > cant use -o hdmi

Tags: video, hdmi

Im trying to watch twitch.tv streams with omxplayer and livestreamer. 
Running the Pi Foundation raspian.
I got it working, there is just a little problem with the sound:

command I am using:

```
livestreamer twitch.tv/$PUTGAMECHANNELHERE best -np omxplayer
```

It does the job really well - except the fact that sound is not being send to hdmi!

I think that the problem is omxplayer! 
By default when i play a video with omxplayer there is no sound on hdmi.
But after setting an alias (`alias omxplayer='omxplayer --adev hdmi'`) it does work and i can hear sound via hdmi.

The Problem is that the alias doesnt seem to work when using omxplayer with livestreamer. Also i cannot set the -o hdmi parameter to the livestreamer start command (`livestreamer twitch.tv/$PUTGAMECHANNELHERE best -np omxplayer -o hdmi` doesnt work).

Any Solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alias does not work for 1 or 2 reasons.  The 1st is that aliases are not expanded by default for non-interactive shells.  The 2nd is that the alias may not even be defined for non-interactive shells, depending on where you defined the alias (stuff in "bashrc" files is never loaded for non-interactive shells).

If the alias is defined (eg, because it is in an applicable "profile" file), then you can set:

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

to use *all defined aliases* in non-interactive shells.  Doing that *in general* is probably not desirable, so one idea is to put all this together in a script:

```
alias omxplayer='omxplayer -o hdmi'
shopt -s expand_aliases 
livestreamer twitch.tv/$PUTGAMECHANNELHERE best -np omxplayer
```

And execute that.

## However

You might first try just quoting the argument to livestreamer:

```
-np "omxplayer -o hdmi"
```

To see if that works, which is probably a better solution than relying on an alias.

Comment: thx - quoting did the job! it works with:
`livestreamer twitch.tv/$PUTGAMECHANNELHERE best -np 'omxplayer -o hdmi'`